# How do I update a record value using the existing value in web2py?

Tags: web2py

Suppose I have a table customer with a field `number_of_times_contacted`.  Now I want to update this field value by adding one to the existing value of every record with last name equal to Smith.  In pseudocode I want to do something like:

```
db(db.customer.last_name == "Smith").update(
     number_of_times_contacted = number_of_times_contacted + 1)
```

What is the expression to do this?  Or do I have do get the customer record first and then update?

Also would the expression be any different for updating a single record by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db(db.customer.last_name == "Smith").update(
   number_of_times_contacted=db.customer.number_of_times_contacted + 1)
```

No different if updating a single record by ID.

Regarding your follow-up question, the exact function(s) will depend on the particular database system, but something like this:

```
from gluon.dal import Expression
db(db.customer.last_name == "Smith").update(
   last_name=Expression(db, 'LTRIM(RTRIM(last_name))'))
```

Comment: Congrats on hitting 10k

Comment: What about if I wanted to update all the last names to be the trimmed version of the last name?  e.g. Convert lastname such as " Smith " to "Smith"

Comment: See updated answer. You can use the `dal.Expression` class to specify arbitrary SQL expressions if necessary.